# DataTables pagination issues: working with Laravel's pagination model and JSON response

Tags: html, jquery, json, laravel, datatables

I am trying to build a datatable for a webpage that will eventually hold hundreds of thousands of entries. Because pagination is a must-have, I was given certain local API-calls that implemented Laravel's paginate method. As a result, the server's JSON response has the following format:

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [{...,
    }],
    "first_page_url": "http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000\/api\/test_history\/fullObj?page=1",
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 134,
    "last_page_url": "http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000\/api\/test_history\/fullObj?page=134",
    "links": [{...,
    }],
    "next_page_url": "http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000\/api\/test_history\/fullObj?page=2",
    "path": "http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000\/api\/test_history\/fullObj",
    "per_page": 15,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 15,
    "total": 2000
}
```

**QUESTION**

*How could DataTables' paging feature implement Laravel's or any pagination model?*

*What changes in the table initialization, or in general, can be made in order for the page buttons to properly call the appropriate batch of entries?*

There should be a way to utilize the above model's `next_page_url`, `first_page_url`, etc. properties.

Due to a predicted vast amount of entries, calling the entire object is out of the question, so, unless I am mistaken, DataTables' default paging may not do, because it is not a matter of what is rendered in the front end.

**ISSUES**

Even though the above JSON response contains all the necessary information for a table pagination, it seems to be conflicting with whatever data the datatable is expecting. So, the following issues surfaced within the webpage:

- The total number of pages within the pagination section was not showing
- Clicking on any page number, or the next/previous buttons within the pagination section loaded the same entries
- The searching and sorting features have stopped filtering the table results

After consulting with documentation, I found that the server's JSON response did not follow [DataTables standards](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side), and I had to manipulate some of the data. Here follows the jQuery used to initialize the datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test_table').DataTable( {
    "order": [[ 8, "desc" ]],
    "scrollX": true,
    "paging": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[ 5, 15, 25, 100, -1 ], [ 5, 15, 25, 100, "All" ]],
    "pageLength": 15,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": function(data, callback, settings) {
      $.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test_history/fullObj?page=1", {
        limit: data.length,
        offset: data.start
      },
      function(json) {
        callback({
          recordsTotal: json.total,
          recordsFiltered: json.total,
          data: json.data
        });
      });
    },
    "columns": [
      { "data": "id" },
      { "data": "uid" },
      { "data": "dev_type.type" },
      { "data": "registers.id" },
      { "data": "measurements.id" },
      { "data": "created_at" },
      { "data": "updated_at" }
    ]
  });
});
```

Alternatively:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test_table').DataTable( {
    "order": [[ 8, "desc" ]],
    "scrollX": true,
    "paging": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[ 5, 15, 25, 100, -1 ], [ 5, 15, 25, 100, "All" ]],
    "pageLength": 15,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
      "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test_history/fullObj?page=1",
      "dataSrc": function(json) {
        json.recordsTotal = json.total;
        json.recordsFiltered = json.total;
        return json.data;
      }
    },
    "columns": [
      { "data": "id" },
      { "data": "uid" },
      { "data": "dev_type.type" },
      { "data": "registers.id" },
      { "data": "measurements.id" },
      { "data": "created_at" },
      { "data": "updated_at" }
    ]
  });
});
```

These response manipulations fixed the issues of the number of pages not showing, and the incorrect number of page buttons. The rest, however, do persist.

**METHODS**

Apart from scouring the DataTables' documentation and their website's forum, and combing through the internet for possible solutions, I have tried the following:

- Attempting to access an HTML class or ID to create a click event, either by adding the attribute or by creating a handler for the event, possibly not getting it right
- Iterating across all numbered buttons, through their DataTables-specific attributes, to dynamically load new entries on click

I have yet to stumble upon a groundbreaking answer, or think of one. Despite these shortcomings, I do believe that the answer is usually simpler than any complex thinking, and in my case it could be related to the data the table is expecting from the server; the JSON's format, or its properties.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've just ran into this myself. Did you make any progress or abandon it?
I agree we should be able to make use of the response from Eloquents paginate method into a datatable initialization. I'm going to be looking at maybe building an adapter as a plugin if need be.

Comment: @PaulAllsopp I ended up creating my own paginator, lending it functionality based on the response by Eloquent. However, recently I managed to use DataTables' own ajax method to pass an index and the page's length and let the library handle the pagination correctly, without customizations. I will share my findings as an answer here, tailored to this example, once I find time today.

Comment: Thanks. After failing every simple way I just choose to ditch datatables as it has a lot of features I don't use anyway. It only took me a single night to create my own version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What finally worked for the question's example, was using the DataTables' `ajax.data` property to pass pagination-related parameters, more specifically the current page. After the initialization, DataTables can handle the server's response so long as the returned object has a certain structure.

Below is the reworked section of the table's initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let currentDraw = 1;

    $("#test_table").DataTable({
        order: [[8, "desc"]],
        scrollX: true,
        paging: true,
        lengthMenu: [
          [5, 15, 25, 100, -1],
          [5, 15, 25, 100, "All"],
        ],
        pageLength: 15,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test_history",
            type: "GET",
            data: function (d) {
                d.page = d.start / d.length + 1;
            },
            dataSrc: function (response) {
                let data = {
                    draw: currentDraw,
                    recordsTotal: response.total,
                    recordsFiltered: response.total,
                    data: response.data,
                };

                currentDraw++;

                return data.data;
            },
        },
        columns: [
            { data: "id" },
            { data: "uid" },
            { data: "dev_type.type" },
            { data: "registers.id" },
            { data: "measurements.id" },
            { data: "created_at" },
            { data: "updated_at" },
        ],
    });
});
```

Apart from passing the current page as an argument sent to the server, calculated as shown, in order for DataTables to detect and use the server's pagination, the structuring of a specific object in the `ajax.dataSrc` property is needed.

Within the newly structured object, a `draw` property is needed, which essentially is the number of times this particular table has been redrawn with data, i.e., each time a page changes. A `recordsTotal` property is needed to calculate the pagination buttons' numbering, and a `recordsFiltered` property to calculate the displayed info about the user's current position within the table on the bottom-left. Each time this callback function is invoked within the `ajax.dataSrc` section, the table's current draw is incremented to ensure that it is correctly attached as a URL parameter and the new data are returned.

I used this implementation within a Node.js and Angular application, as well as a static website, and the above was all both DataTables and the server needed. I hope this is helpful.